# Why does for(var i in Math) not iterate through Math.* in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For some reason for(var i in Math){console.log(i)} doesn't show the expected tan, cos, atan2, E, PI in Javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `Math` is a built in object whose properties are flagged **non-enumerable**. Many built in objects have this behavior, which is why looping over an array with `for..in` will not give you problems until `Array.prototype` is extended with user functions, which are always enumerable by default.

Until recently **non-enumerable** was an internal property not accessible by regular Javascript code. However EMCAScript 5 specifies the ability to set the enumerability and writeability (try changing the value of `Math.PI`) of any object property through [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

It also provides [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) as a way to get a list of all properties of an object regardless of their enumerability.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);

//returns
["LN10", "PI", "E", "LOG10E", "SQRT2", "LOG2E", "SQRT1_2", "LN2", "cos", "pow", "log", "tan", "sqrt", "ceil", "asin", "abs", "max", "exp", "atan2", "random", "round", "floor", "acos", "atan", "min", "sin"]
```

Far as I know the only browsers that currently support these functions are Chrome and Safari. Firefox should support it at version 4. IE9 I am not sure about, but Microsoft has stated they intend to support the EMCAScript 5 standard eventually.

I do not believe there is any way to emulate this functionality in Javascript interpreters without explicit support.

Answer (score 5):

As with most built-in objects in JavaScript, properties and methods of the `Math` object are defined in the ECMAScript spec (section 15.8.1) as not being enumerable via the (inaccessible to script) `DontEnum` attribute. In ECMAScript 5, you can mark properties and methods of your own objects as being non-enumerable also:

```
var o = {};

Object.defineProperty(o, "p", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: 1
});

Object.defineProperty(o, "q", {
    enumerable: true,
    value: 2
});

for (var i in o) {
    console.log(i + "=>" + o[i]);
}
// q=>2
```

Answer (score 2):

Those properties are non-enumerable.

From [the MDC documentation on for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in#Description):

> A for...in loop does not iterate over built-in properties.

In newer JavaScript implementations you can make your own non-enumerable properties. Check out [propertyIsEnumerable()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) and [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 0):

I keep noticing when the actual method is not known people will tell you you shoud'nt do it

The following is the way to expose private functions of a given object

```
let exposeFunctionsOf  =(obj) =>
{
    let iterated = false
    for ( let k in obj ) 
    {
        iterated = true;
        let prop = obj[k]
        if ( typeof props == "function")
        {
            window[k] = prop
        }
    }
    if (!iterated)
    {
       let props_names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
       for (let prop_name of props_names)
       {
          iterated = true;
          let prop = obj[prop_name]
          if ( typeof prop == "function")
            window[prop_name] =prop
       }
    }
    if (!iterated)
    {
      console.warn("failed to iterate through the following object")
      cosnole.log(obj)
    }
}
```

Applied on `Math` object

```
exposeFunctionsOf(Math)
```

Now you can write `sin(x)` instead of `Math.sin(x)`

Enjoy